# Nifi: use dynamic variable in RouteOnAttribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm developping a Nifi flow that is getting data from an API every 30 sec. These data are in json format and I'm filtering it using an EvaluateJsonPath and RouteOnAttribute processors.
I splited the json Array I receive from the API and each json object contains a field "StationName" that i'm using to filter the data.
[getting and filtering the json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdpyD.png)

When I'm hard coding the filter in the RouteOnAttribute like this `${stationName:equals("Kensal Green Station") :or(${stationName:equals("Sudbury & Harrow Road Station")}) :or(${stationName:equals("Wembley Central Station")}) :or......` every thing works well

The problem is that I want to create a dynamic filter that contains a list of stations coming from a reference file. I made a flow that is getting that file, reading it and put a station in a variable (I started with the whole list of station names but atfer many fails I decided to try with just one value to begin).

On the screens below you can see that variable "stopsList" and its value "Heathrow Central Bus Station". Then you can see my dynamic filter in the RouteOnAttribute processor.

[reference data coming from the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz6TB.png)

[value of my attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gGrf.png)

[the dynamic filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHuqN.png)

The thing is when I play the whole flow, all the values are going in the "unmatched" path, I got nothing that match with my filter (but if I hard code it, it works).

[everything goes wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Otba.png)

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you for reading me,

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: I would say you need lookuprecord processor https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Data-flow-enrichment-with-NiFi-part-1-LookupRecord-processor/ta-p/246940

Comment: The issue that for your "dynamic filter" both attributes must be in the same flow file.